# How to resolve `unable to locate package` error?

Tags: package-management, tinyos

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` to add `deb http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos/dists/ubuntu precise main`. But when I try to install `tinyos`; I get the following error:

```
shahid@shahid-Lenovo-G550:~$ sudo apt-get install tinyos
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tinyos
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you add a different source in `/etc/apt/sources.list`; you would also have to run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This retrieves the new list of packages and knows what are the different packages available for installation and where to download it from.

Once you have run the above command, you may proceed with installation of `tinyos`:

```
sudo apt-get install tinyos
```

Answer (score 0):

You might still have to do other things to get your package to work. I am still unable to download wine after adding its repository and updating the packages multiple times

Comment: It does not answer the question. Specify what are "other things".